Generic function with keyof-generic return
type  Base  ={
    id: string
}

type Foo = Base & {
  foo: string
}

const isFoo = (obj: any): obj is Foo => {
  return 'foo' in obj
}


const getSomeKeyOfGeneric = <M extends Base>(obj: M):(keyof M)[] => {
  if (isFoo(obj)) {
    return (['id', 'foo'] as (keyof Foo)[]) as (keyof M)[]
  }

  return []
}

I cannot remove the as casts otherwise:

remove first will lose all type checks - I could use string[] as return
remove second will raise TypeScript error

Playground

What you're doing isn't type safe. You are returning keyof Foo, not keyof M. M might be wider than Foo, as shown in this playground link. Here M is just Base, and keyof M is "id". So you need type assertions (what you're calling a "cast") or you need to change to use Foo instead of M in your return type. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

I'm just curious, why is it that you are trying to avoid to simply return string[] type as you mentioned. Any specific reason you can share with us? If you give us some more context, this could help to some degree.
BTW, I posted an answer yesterday, but because I've used ChatGPT to form a nice .md answer, despite the fact that I've tested the code on my local machine and done the leg work, I got into trouble, so they removed my answer and I agree, I deserved it - I should have known better. Anyway I am super interested in solving this one.

When using string[] I cannot be sure that the returned keys actually exist on given object. I try to narrow the type by using the typeguards.

Could you please respond to my comment above? You cannot assume that "foo" is a key of M, just because it is a key of obj. Values can have properties not mentioned in their types. All you know for sure is that you're returning keyof Foo, or perhaps keyof M | keyof Foo (except your example never grabs a key from obj, so keyof Foo is more precise).
